# How do I get the data within a specific range of datetime in a .txt file

Tags: python, text

Alright, I'm pretty new to coding in general and as of now I am using Python. I'm trying to filter information from a .txt file. The file is a log of activities, starting at 00:00:00 and ending at 23:59:59. I need the lines from 07:00:00 to 19:00:00. How do I achieve such results?

I can get data from specific date time, but haven't figured out how to get exactly what I am looking for.

Here is a reduced sample of the .txt file:

```
08:07:21: -------------------------------------------
08:07:21: Make launched. OMAX Intelli-MAX� Premium 21.0
08:07:21: "LLAMA" is currently logged in to windows.
08:08:20: Home named "Path Interrupted" zeroed.
08:09:31: Home named "Path Start" zeroed.
08:09:40: Home named "Path Start" zeroed.
08:11:49: Home named "Path Start" zeroed.
08:33:13: Home named "Path Finished" zeroed.
08:34:24: Make Closed.
09:04:14: -------------------------------------------
09:04:14: Make launched. OMAX Intelli-MAX� Premium 21.0
09:04:14: "LLAMA" is currently logged in to windows.
09:04:43: Home named "Path Interrupted" zeroed.
09:05:54: Home named "Path Start" zeroed.
09:06:00: Home named "Path Start" zeroed.
09:09:48: Home named "Path Start" zeroed.
09:28:15: Home named "Path Finished" zeroed.
09:41:38: Make Closed.
20:04:20: Home named "Path Finished" zeroed.
20:07:50: Automatic homing routine activated.
20:13:14: Home named "Absolute" zeroed.
20:13:14: Automatic homing routine completed.
21:15:05: Make Closed.
```

In the end, I want to calculate how long a job takes. for instance, the time difference between a "Path Start" and a "Path Finished". But what i am asking here is simply how to just read lines between 07:00:00 and 19:00:00.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to read every lines 1 by 1, and check if beginning contains 19, 20, etc. Again pretty new at this, it doesn't work. I'm trying to find a simple and great way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to parse to `datetime.datetime` objects, maybe like this:

```
import datetime

line_list = []
start_datetime = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0)
end_datetime = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 19, 0, 0)

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[:8], '%H:%M:%S')

            if start_datetime <= dt <= end_datetime:
                line_list.append(line)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for the output, I've got much more to learn!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a basic strategy of reading each line and then filtering it.

```py
output = []

with open('info.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        h = int(line.split(':')[0])    # Get the hour

        if 7 <= h <= 19:               # Check if the hour is in range
            output.append(line)
```

Comment: This wont work because it catches the time 19:55:01 for example